# How to place a class using if condition to mark pagination active page using css for following code?

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to put an if condition like `<?php if($page===$x) {echo ' class="selected"';}?>` to use CSS for marking the selected page in my pagination for the following code:

```
<?php
$result = $DB_con->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_users');
$totalRecords = $result->fetchColumn();
$totalPages = max(1, ceil($totalRecords / $recordsPerPage));

for ($i=1; $i<=$totalPages; $i++) {
echo "<span class='navigations_items_span'>";

//if($page===$i) echo "<b>Visiting Page</b>"; 
echo "<b>Page </b>";
echo "<a href='index3.php?page=".$i."' class='navigation_item selected_navigation_item'>. ".$i.".</a>";


echo "</span>";
};
?>
```

I wanted to place in the line : `echo "<a href='index3.php?page=".$i."' class='navigation_item selected_navigation_item'>. ".$i.".</a>";` but getting error each time, how to place if here?

please help.

Comment: I wanted to place in the line echo "<a href='index3.php?page=".$i."' class='navigation_item selected_navigation_item'>. ".$i.".</a>";

Comment: What error you get?

Answer (score 0):

inside your `for` loop :

```
if($page == $i)
    $class = 'navigation_item selected_navigation_item';
else
    $class = '';

echo "<a href='index3.php?page=".$i."' class='".$class."'>. ".$i.".</a>";
```

Comment: I have already have the $page variable and I am getting the url number correctly. My problem is I can print additional statement like "Visiting Page=2" only I was trying to add a class for css called "selected" and was trying to change color of the "selected page pagination number" as existing selected selected_navigation_item was marking all numbers like image bellow https://i.imgsafe.org/ebcba9626b.png        when css class defined as:
.selected_navigation_item{
border: 2px solid #004D80;
border-radius: 2px;
color: #004D80 !important;
background: red;
margin-right: 5px;
}